# Does JSON.stringify recognize properties defined with Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript

Does `JSON.stringify` work with objects that are created like

```
obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', {
  get: function() { return 1 }
  set: function(value) { ... }
})
```

It returns `{}` when called on this object.

Comment: http://npmjs.org/package/dictionary

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You might want to set the enumerable option to true, like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(o, 'test', {
    get: function () { return 1; },
    enumerable: true
});
```

Comment: I don't know why they didn't make enumerable:true the default. It was causing me quite the headache when I tried to convert to JSON.

Comment: That works fine with object not not classes :(

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Well, class instances are just objects. You could call the above code on `this` in the class's constructor.

Comment: Yeah that's what I just found out (I was using the prototype), thx !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Note that you can still reuse the same function instance rather than creating a new one inline.